# Get text between capture groups

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I am given a regex like the following:

```
(\/*).*?(\*/)
```

Using this regex, I need to transform some text from:

```
/* This is a comment */
```

To:

```
([/*] This is a comment [*/])
```

Both the regex and the transformation rules are given to me; I can't ask for a different regex format.

I could do this easily if I could reliably split text into a sequence of capture groups and non-captured text. However, this doesn't seem to be possible in general using javascript regexes, because `exec` does not save information about the indexes of individual matches. Is there a solution?

Comment: *"Both the regex and the transformation rules are given to me; I can't ask for a different regex format."* Um....?! Fixing the regex is the correct way to fix this.

Comment: And note that using regular expressions to handle comments in the various languages using syntax like yours above is prone to failure.

Comment: The `(*/)` is not a valid regex. Opening symbol of a grouping construct cannot be quantified.

Comment: Yeah, there's some missing escapes above...

Comment: `(\/\*)(.*?)(\*\/)` -- https://regex101.com/r/fBR1IU/1

Comment: I can't change what expressions I'm given. Therefore, changing which expressions I'm given is not a solution, let alone "the correct" solution. If there is a reliable way to transform the given regexes into something more convenient, then that would be a solution.

Comment: So essentially, what you are saying is, you want to capture something which is not being captured. *I can't ask for a different regex format* Who is this mysterious person dictating your regexps? The correct answer is, "well then, you can't ask for the output you want".

Comment: *If there is a reliable way to transform the given regexes* It's going to be very hard to build something to transform a broken, incorrect regexp.

Comment: This mysterious person is an existing Sublime Text syntax definition. Sublime's parser uses onigurama, which absolutely does expose all of the necessary information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regexp to transform your regexp by adding additional capture groups:

```js
function addCapture(reg) {
  return new RegExp(reg.source.replace(/\(.*?\)|[^(]*/g,
    match => match[0] === '(' ? match : `(${match})`), reg.flags);
}

const regexp = /(\/\*).*?(\*\/)/;
const input = "/* This is a comment */";

console.log(input.replace(addCapture(regexp), '[$1]$2[$3]'));
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g. using `String.prototype.replace()`, you can refer the capturing groups by their indices:

```js
var input = '/* This is a comment */'

var output = input.replace(/(\/\*)(.*)(\*\/)/, '([$1]$2[$3])')

console.log(output); // "([/*] This is a comment [*/])"
```

Comment: But he said he can't change the regexp.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not address my problem, which is performing the replacement using a *given* regex.